# How can you install all dependencies need for a project in conda?

Tags: python, dependencies, conda, environment

I only have python files which require some packages to be installed. I have conda installe on my computer as well. I just have the code, the project is not running anywhere at the moment. I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59940841/how-to-install-all-dependencies-of-a-python-project-using-conda), however as far as I understand an assumption of this solution is that you run the export command from running environment. I don't have the environment, only the code which has import statements inside. Is there a way to automatically install all packages needed?

Comment: Does this link help? https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/download.html

Comment: I have conda installed. I see no other information regarding my problem.

Comment: Have you tried creating an enviroment?  `conda create --name your_env_name python=3.7 -y`

Comment: And also 


 https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/install-packages/ for installing conda packages

Comment: You should specify your dependencies in a `requirements.txt` or `env.yaml` file for pip or conda respectively.

Comment: @Alex, do you know if there is a way to create the .yaml code just out of python code?

Comment: @BorutFlis there is [yolk](https://pypi.org/project/yolk/) or [snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/) though I have never used these. Here are some related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796968/get-all-modules-packages-used-by-a-python-project and https://stackoverflow.com/a/509194/3279716

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all modules/packages used by a python project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796968/get-all-modules-packages-used-by-a-python-project)